# 404 on i18n json files

Tags: angular-universal, spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to enable i18n json files with SSR on assets folder following this docs:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/

But when enabled, all files in PT folder results 404 error.
[image]

Here's my provideConfig on spartacus-configuration.module.ts file:
[image]

and my assets folder:

[image]

Thanks for your time, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's trying to load a bunch of json files that aren't in your directories.

What I did on mine was I provided original Spartacus translations then I added mine below that:

```
  provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
    i18n: {
      resources: translations,
      chunks: translationChunksConfig,
      fallbackLang: 'en'
    },
  }), 
  provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
    i18n: {
      backend: {
        loadPath: 'assets/i18n-assets/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        chunks: {
          footer: ['footer']
        }
      }
    },
  })
```

otherwise, you can try to add those files its complaining about (orderApproval.json, savedCart.json, etc) to your 'pt' folder (not sure what language that is but perhaps Spartacus doesn't come with translations for it)